# SQL: Get all values in column without using "case when"

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql

```
key |  num 
--------------
 A  |  2.6
 A  |  3.1
 B  |  2.5
 C  |  2.7
```

Let's say I have a table as shown above, and I want the percent of `key` observations that take the value A. I can do this using the following `case when` statements:

```
sum(case when key = 'A' then 1.0 else 0 end)/count(*) as A_pct
```

However, if I have lots of values for `key` then I would have to write lots of `case when` statements. Is there a simpler way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this below script. This will return percentage for all distinct keys.

```
SELECT 
Key,
(COUNT(*)/(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM your_table)*1.00)*100.00 
FROM your_table
GROUP BY Key
```

If percentage is not required, then just do this as your sample code

```
SELECT 
Key,
COUNT(*)/(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM your_table)*1.00
FROM your_table
GROUP BY Key
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use aggregation if it is good enough to have the values in separate rows rather than columns:

```
select key, count(*), count(*) * 1.0 / sum(count(*)) over () as ratio
from t
group by key;
```

The `* 1.0` is simply because I'm not sure whether or not SparkSQL does integer division.  If you want a value from 0 to 100, then use `* 100.0`.